# Incrementar uno el valor de un campo de bd

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una web creada con php, mysql, javascript y html. Os comento a ver si me podéis ayudar...

Tengo un select creado con HTML que me lo rellena mediante una consulta a mi Base de Datos.

```
<div id="listaCategorias2">
    <p  name="title"> 2. Seleccione una fotografía.
            <select id="listImgNew"disabled selected style="visibility:hidden">
                <option selected value="0" > Elige una opción </option>
                    <option value="1" id="tituloAntiguas">
                    <?php
                    $sql_imagenes=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM imagenes_nuevas");
                            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_imagenes)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['titulo'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
</div id="contenedor">
<input type="submit" value="Votar" onclick="ShowSelected();">  </input>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Después quiero que el SELECT seleccionado al pulsar un INPUT TYPE="submit", me ejecute una consulta en la que sume 1 al campo voto...pero no lo consigo...

Realizando pruebas, mediante este código, consigo mostrar el valor del select.

```
<script>
    
    function ShowSelected(){
        let cod = document.getElementById("listImgNew").value;
        alert(cod);
    }
</script>
```

La pregunta es... ¿Como puedo hacer para que si el valor del SELECT sea igual al valor de mi ID en mi BD me sume 1 a la columna votos que tengo en la BD?

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

---

Este es el código que tengo por el momento...

```
        <?php
    include 'header.php';
    session_start();
    include("conexion.php");
    ?>
    
    <!-- Bloquea boton derecho -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false}
    </script>
    
    <script>
            <!-- Muestra valor del select -->
            function ShowSelected(){
                let cod = document.getElementById("listImgNew").value;
                alert(cod);
            }
        </script>
    
    <html>
    <head>
<!-- Función que habilita y deshabilita los list -->
            <script>
                    function select(){
                let selectedValue = document.getElementById("listImg").value;
                if(selectedValue == 0){
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                else if (selectedValue == 1){
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").disabled=false;
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").disabled=true; 
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").style.visibility = "hidden";
    
                }else if (selectedValue == 2){
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").disabled=false; 
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("listImgNew").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("listImgAnt").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("title2").style.display = "block";
                }}
            </script>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panelPrinci">
<!-- Bienvenida de usuario -->
            <h1><?php echo "BIENVENIDO/A ";
            echo  $_SESSION['usuario'];?></h1>
    <!-- Cierre de sesion -->
            <form action='cerrarSesion.php' class="formSocios">
                <input type="submit" value="Cerrar sesión" class="sesionSocio"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    
        <div id="textoSocio">
            <p> Has accedido al Sistema de Votación del Concurso de fotografía. Desde aquí, podrás realizar el voto a una fotografía de cada categoría.</p><br/><br/>
            
              <p><strong><u> RECUERDE: Unicamente podrá realizar un único voto a una fotografía de ambas categorias </p></strong></u>  <br/>
            <!-- Listas desplegables completadas con consulta a la BD -->
        </div>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="listGaleria">
                <p> 1. ¿Que categoría quieres votas?
                    <select id="listImg" onchange="select();">
                        <option selected value="0"> Elige una opción </option>
                            <option value="1">Fotografías Antiguas</option> 
                            <option value="2">Fotografías Actuales</option>
                        </optgroup> 
                    </select>
                </p>
            </div>
    
            <div id="listaCategorias">
                <p name="title"> 2. Seleccione una fotografía.
                    <select id="listImgAnt"disabled selected name="select" style="visibility:hidden">
                        <option selected value="0" > Elige una opción </option>
                            <option value="1" id="tituloAntiguas">
                            <?php
                            $sql_imagenes=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM imagenes_antiguas");
                                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_imagenes)) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['titulo'].'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </div>
    
            <div id="listaCategorias2">
            <p  name="title"> 2. Seleccione una fotografía.
                    <select id="listImgNew"disabled selected style="visibility:hidden">
                        <option selected value="0" > Elige una opción </option>
                            <option value="1" id="tituloAntiguas">
                            <?php
                            $sql_imagenes=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM imagenes_nuevas");
                                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_imagenes)) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['titulo'].'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div id="contenedor">
        <input type="submit" value="Votar" onclick="ShowSelected();">  </input>
    
    </body>
    </html>
        <?php
        include 'footer.php'
        ?>
```

A partir de aqui...no consigo avanzar...por más pruebas que hago con la consulta de MySQL, pasando las variables y demás...no lo consigo

Ya que me recomendais el AJAX, como sería, porque con AJAX nunca he programado.

Comment: No entendí la pregunta. ¿Hablas de un auto incremental o lo que quieres es un acumulador que se incremente de 1 en 1? Tampoco queda claro en qué columna de la BD debería ocurrir el cambio ni qué código ejecutas para hacer dicho cambio. Parecería que lo más conveniente aquí sería usar Ajax y lanzar una consulta del tipo `UPDATE`

Comment: Lo mismo no me he sabido explicar...que es lo mas seguro... Lo que quiero es un metodo o alguna forma para que cuando yo seleccione un valor del SELECT del HTML me sume 1 en la columna VOTO de mi BD.

La consulta para que he probado es: 
UPDATE (nombre_tabla) SET voto = voto +1 where voto = ? 

Donde la interrogación quiero que sea el valor del SELECT de HTML

Comment: Es el buen camino, sólo que en el `WHERE` debes poner el `id` de la fila que quieres actualizar el cual tendrías que enviar cuando lanzas la consulta de actualización. Y, como sugerí antes, lo mejor es usar Ajax para esto. Sea como sea, no veo tu código de actuaiización ni qué lógica estás implementando.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está aquí:

```
<select id="listImgNew" disabled selected style="visibility:hidden">
```

El `$_POST` no está recibiendo ningún valor, porque no le estás mandando ningún valor. El `POST` requiere que tu elemento `SELECT` tenga la propiedad `NAME`, no `ID`. `ID` está bien pero para JavaScript, como lo has visto. La forma correcta debe ser:

```
<select id="listImgNew" name="listImgNew" disabled selected style="visibility:hidden">
```

Y ahora si, en tu script de procesamiento ya puedes leer la variable `$_POST["listImgNew"]`, y quedaría algo así como:

```
<?php
$q = "UPDATE (nombre_tabla) SET voto = voto +1 where voto = $_POST['listImgNew']";
mysqli_query($db, $q) or die('Ocurrió un error');
...
```

---

Si lo estás intentando hacer con Ajax como te recomiendan en los comentarios, deberías entonces si, armar la llamada al Ajax con la variable como la estás tomando y mandarle el diccionario que contenga el nombre del id y el valor.